# "%1" Application under Change options in Properties window

Tags: windows-10

I noticed something strange on my Windows 10 PC and I'm wondering if someone can explain.

### Strange Observation

When I select `Properties` > `Change` on a .jpg or .png file and view the list of available applications, there is an application simply labeled **"%1"**—double quotes included.

[image]

This option is not listed for *.pdf, .docx, .mp4, .pptx, or any other non-picture file types as far as I can tell*  although I have not checked .gif and maybe other 
 file types.

**I have searched** for this application in my system files and cannot find it. This option is also not available in the regular `Open With`... list—it only appears in the Change list. I have not tried to open any file with this application in case it is harmful since I don't understand why this is there.

### Question

Can anyone explain what is this, how to prevent it, or find out further details about what it might be?

Comment: I dont have that option on my W10 ver 1903, can you post a screenshot?

Comment: You got some rubbish in your registry.

Comment: `%1` means "the first command line parameter". (google: command line param in batch file). As to how it made it into the list, no idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is discussed on the [Help how to remove "%1" application in "choose default program/how do you want to open this file?"](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/help-how-to-remove-1-application-in-choose-default/1d84241e-fbd7-498b-8da9-458d9ef07036) post from 2014 with two solutions talked about but I've dug into it with a little more detail to see what's causing it specifically.

---

### The Issue

The issue seems to be with certain versions of QuickTime perhaps creating correlated registry settings that cause the erroneous `"%1"` to be listed in the `Open With` | `Choose Another App` | `How do you want to open this file?` pop up screen ***due to white space before the `"%1"` value.***

> The problem is with Windows Registry entries that QuickTime creates.
>   Apple should correct all of the reg data that is listed below. I have
>   started a discussion about this issue in Apple forum
>   https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6699484
>
> ```
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\QuickTime.bmp\shell\open\command]
> @=" \"%1\""
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\QuickTime.dib\shell\open\command]
> @=" \"%1\""
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\QuickTime.jp2\shell\open\command]
> @=" \"%1\""
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\QuickTime.jpe\shell\open\command]
> @=" \"%1\""
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\QuickTime.jpeg\shell\open\command]
> @=" \"%1\""
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\QuickTime.jpg\shell\open\command]
> @=" \"%1\""
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\QuickTime.mac\shell\open\command]
> @=" \"%1\""
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\QuickTime.pct\shell\open\command]
> @=" \"%1\""
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\QuickTime.pic\shell\open\command]
> @=" \"%1\""
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\QuickTime.pict\shell\open\command]
> @=" \"%1\""
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\QuickTime.png\shell\open\command]
> @=" \"%1\""
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\QuickTime.pnt\shell\open\command]
> @=" \"%1\""
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\QuickTime.pntg\shell\open\command]
> @=" \"%1\""
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\QuickTime.psd\shell\open\command]
> @=" \"%1\""
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\QuickTime.qti\shell\open\command]
> @=" \"%1\""
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\QuickTime.qtif\shell\open\command]
> @=" \"%1\""
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\QuickTime.rgb\shell\open\command]
> @=" \"%1\""
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\QuickTime.sgi\shell\open\command]
> @=" \"%1\""
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\QuickTime.targa\shell\open\command]
> @=" \"%1\""
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\QuickTime.tga\shell\open\command]
> @=" \"%1\""
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\QuickTime.tif\shell\open\command]
> @=" \"%1\""
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\QuickTime.tiff\shell\open\command]
> @=" \"%1\""
> ```
>
> [Source](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/help-how-to-remove-1-application-in-choose-default/1d84241e-fbd7-498b-8da9-458d9ef07036)

---

### Solutions

1. Install the latest version of [QuickTime](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL837) which according to some people this resolves the issue
2. Manually remove\delete\correct the erroneous data from the correlated registry keys as needed and remove the leading white space.

   > ### The Leading White Space Cause
   >
   > This issue can be easily recreated on a Windows 10 machine 
   >   by preceding a white space before the 
   >   `Value data:` "value" within a specific registry setting. If you remove the
   >   leading white space, the issue goes away and the option is not listed as does removing the value
   >   entirely although I'm not entirely sure what else that will affect.
   >
   > [image] 
   >   [image]

Comment: Thanks, mah dude. Re-downloading Quicktime did nothing but manually changing the key value solved it. No scripting needed, it was just the .jpg and .png files which was easy enough to change manually. Thanks, again!